# Cookie added to Response.Cookies is also added to Request.Cookies. Any way to get to the original Request.Cookies?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

If I add a cookie to the response via `Response.Cookies.Add()`, the cookie also appears in `Request.Cookies`.

Is there any way to get to the original request cookies (ignoring newly added response cookies) without somehow caching `Request.Cookies` in advance?

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406141/why-is-cookie-available-in-request-immediately-after-setting-using-response) that asks why this situation exists (a point that I'm clear on). I'm asking if there's any way around it.

### Update

As a very rough filter, it seems you can look for cookies in `Request.Cookies` whose `Expires` is equal to `default(DateTime)`. This is because when browsers serialize their cookies in the request, they don't include their expiration dates.

However, this wouldn't get rid of any cookies accidentally added to `Response` without an `Expires`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Request.Headers["Cookie"]` contains the raw header value sent by the browser. It's a semicolon-delimited list of key-value pairs. E.g.,:

```
key1=value1; key2=value2
```

Which can be parsed to a `Dictionary<string, string>` to figure out the request's original cookies (ignoring any that were added or modified by manipulating `Request.Cookies` or `Response.Cookies`).

(The values are URI-encoded to avoid any [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) situations for values containing equal signs or semicolons.)